# Is it possible to use angularjs cached resource method in a filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I have a property in the scope that has an id of external object, also I have a filter that expands this id into a full object like this:

```
{{ typeId | expandType }}
```

Filter:

```
.filter('expandType', ['TypeService', function (tsvc) {
  return function (id) {
    return tsvc.types.get({ id: id });
  }
}])
```

where tsvc.types.get() is normal resource get method with added cache option.

```
.factory('TypeService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  var typeResource = $resource('/api/types/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
    get: { method: 'GET', cache: true, params: { id: '@id' } }
  });
  return {
    types: typeResource
  }
}])
```

As I understand angular runs additional digest after the fist one just to make sure that nothing changed. But apparently on the next digest the filter is returning a different object and I get the infdig error (digest is executed in infinite loop).

I hoped that if the resource is cached it will return the same object from cache all the time. I can confirm that there is only one trip to server while executing get() so the cache is working.

What can I do to make it work and use the filter to expand ids to full objects?

Answer (score 0):

Although possible, it is usually not a good idea to bind promises to the view. In your case, filters are reevaluated on every digest, and quoting from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http:

> When the cache is enabled, $http stores the response from the server in the specified cache. The next time the same request is made, the response is served from the cache without sending a request to the server.
>
> Note that even if the response is served from cache, delivery of the data is asynchronous in the same way that real requests are.

To clarify, ngResource uses `$http` internally.

You can still use the filter calling it from your controller:

```
app.filter('expandType', function ($http) {
  return function (id) {
    return $http.get('data.json');
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, expandTypeFilter) {
  var typeId = 'hello';
  
  expandTypeFilter(typeId).success(function (data) {
    $scope.expandedTypeId = data[typeId];
  });
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/BPS9IY?p=preview.

With this approach, if the only reason you were caching the response was to avoid repeated calls to the server, you can now stop caching it so that it gets fresh data later on, but that depends on your needs, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I really wanted to use a filter because it was used all over the app and I didn't want to clutter my controllers. At this point the solution I came out with looks as follows:

```
.filter('expandType', ['TypeService', function (tsvc) {
  var cache = {};
  return function (id) {
    if (!id) {
      return '';
    }
    var type = cache[id];
    if (!type) {
      tsvc.types.get({ id: id }).$promise.then(function (data) {
        cache[id] = data;
      });
      cache[id] = {}
      return cache[id];
    }
    else {
      return type;
    }
  }
}])
```